Foxglove not update topics
ROS2 Jazzy installed and running on raspberrypi 5 with OS Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
Foxglove installed and running on Macbook laptop.
Both devices are in the same local network.
Network topology:
<raspberrypi 5> <-> 
On raspberrypi 5 running Rosbridge as a service (started at the boot with ubuntu service manager (systemctl)
List of available topics on raspberrypi and foxglove are the same, e.g,
ubuntu@rpi:~$ ros2 topic list
/parameter_events
/rosout

Then I run turtlesim on raspberrypi 5
ros2 run turtlesim turtlesim_node

and topic list updated
ubuntu@rpi:~$ ros2 topic list
/parameter_events
/rosout
/turtle1/cmd_vel
/turtle1/color_sensor
/turtle1/pose

but foxglove still shown old list w/o turtles
And even if I restart Rosbridge web socket on raspberrypi 5 nothing changed on foxglove panel.
I've checked user and group the ros2 processes are running under but they are the same.
Then, if I shutdown service that runs Rosbridge web socket on raspberrypi 5 and run it manually from console
ros2 launch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket_launch.xml

Then foxglove displays updated list of topics including ones, that's belong to turtlesim


So, my question is:
why foxglove doesn't see changes from remote ros2 host if the Rosbridge web socket run as a service on ros2 remote host?
Thanks in advance,

When you say "shutdown service that runs Rosbridge web socket on raspberrypi 5 and run it manually from console" you mean from the console of the Macbook?

No - all actions taken on rpi5
